# battery coding Audi A4 2.0 TDI (B8, 2008)

Tags: battery, audi, code, a4

I bought a new battery for my car (exide ea1000) and I installed it. the battery works, but I heard it needs coding. knowing that German cars are fairly sensible to this kind of things, it makes a lot of sense. the only problem is that I can't find a part number or a serial number on the battery. is there a work-around, something that will do the trick with any battery? for example changing 1 digit in the existing serial number and hoping for the best.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!